# How to select a specific numbers of elements within a Data Frame in an efficient way?

Tags: r, performance, loops, apply

I have a data.frame (df) with a few columns. Let's select just the second column in this example. Furthermore my df consists of 150.000 rows and I would like to select every 1330 elements within the column and sum it up. 

For example: **1:** 1 to 1330 **2:** 1331 to 2661 and so on

```
store  <- matrix(nrow=500,0)  # I Have included an object to store my output
j <- 1330                     # index variable to select elements 
k <- 1                        # control variable of my object
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
        store[k,1] <- sum(df[i:j,2],na.rm=T)
        i+1330
        j+1331
        k+1
}
```

**Two problems with my code:** 
**First of all:** After looping I get just one aggregate number in my object "store" AND NOT per 1330 selected elements. I expected 113 totals. 
**Second:** My loop needs a lot of time. How could I code this in a more elegant and in a more efficient way?

Thank you!

Comment: You can try using `tapply(store$COL2, cut(store$COL2, n), FUN=sum)`; where, `store` is your data frame, `COL2` is your column, `n` is the number of cuts (150,000/1330 = ~112).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(ID = floor((row_number()-1)/1330)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(MyColumnToBeSummed))
```

---

**Edit**:

Here's it in action, but summing 10 elements at a time for simplicity.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:100, b = 101:200)

df %>% 
  mutate(ID = floor((row_number()-1)/10)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(a))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
      ID   sum
   <dbl> <int>
 1     0    55
 2     1   155
 3     2   255
 4     3   355
 5     4   455
 6     5   555
 7     6   655
 8     7   755
 9     8   855
10     9   955
```

Let's check a couple of numbers. The last group is `sum(91:100)`, which is 955, and first group is `sum(1:10)`, which is 55. Looks good.

---

**Edit #2**:

To do this for multiple columns, you don't need a loop. Instead, use [`summarise_at`](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/summarise_all.html) (or `summarise_all`).

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:100, b = 101:200, c = 201:300, d = 301:400)

df %>% 
  mutate(ID = floor((row_number()-1)/10)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(a, b, d), funs(sum = sum))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
      ID a_sum b_sum d_sum
   <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
 1     0    55  1055  3055
 2     1   155  1155  3155
 3     2   255  1255  3255
 4     3   355  1355  3355
 5     4   455  1455  3455
 6     5   555  1555  3555
 7     6   655  1655  3655
 8     7   755  1755  3755
 9     8   855  1855  3855
10     9   955  1955  3955
```

Comment: In "sum" I have included an additional attribute "na.rm=T".  But apart from this I got trying this solution for every ID just the total of the column. Is the "floor"-function really correct?

Comment: You can shorten this with: `df %>% 
  group_by(ID = (row_number()-1) %/% 1330) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(MyColumnToBeSummed))`

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not working correctly because I always got the total of the column and not each 1300-elements

Comment: @ira01 Make a reproducible example (not necessarily your actual `df`) and precisely the expected output, so that folks can test their code.

Comment: perfect, thank you for editing your example! My fault was to add to the specific column again my df like df$a. But it's working! thank you again! :)

Comment: And a last question on this: how I could add a loop-function to store for example 10 columns from my dataframe in one single object?

Comment: @ira01 I've updated my answer to show how to do this for multiple columns.

Comment: @Lyngbakr: Many, many thanks for your support! I guess I really should try a tutorial on "dplyr"- package...

Comment: @ira01 You're welcome! `dplyr` is very powerful – as is the rest of the [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org) – so it's well worth learning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following does it.
First, make up some data, since you haven't posted an example.

```
set.seed(3721)
n <- 1.5e5
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n), y = runif(n))
```

Now, using `tapply`,

```
fact <- rep(1:(nrow(df) %/% 1330 + 1), each = 1330, length = nrow(df))
store <- unname(c(tapply(df[[2]], fact, FUN = sum)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This way is a little cheeky but should be efficient as it avoids loops.

```
j <- 1330
second_col <- df[,2]
mat <- matrix(c(second_col, rep(0, j - (length(second_col) %% j))), ncol = j, byrow=TRUE)
store <- rowSums(mat)
```

Comment: You want the `colSums`, but this is an efficient solution.

Comment: I'm not seeing `colSum()` working here, since he wants a vector of length 113 since `ceiling(length(second_col) / 1330)` is 113.  I did just fix a miscalculation with the matrix though so I think it should work now.

Comment: Nevermind, I see the issue, I was filling the matrix in the wrong manner.  Should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can be more efficient by not creating some vector of groups. Instead with Rcpp, you can do:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector sumByPart(const NumericVector& x, int size) {

  int n = x.size();
  int K = ceil((double)n / size); // DO NOT USE INTEGERS WITH CEIL
  IntegerVector res(K);
  int i, k, offset = 0;

  for (k = 0; k < K-1; k++) {
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      res[k] += x[offset + i];
    }
    offset += size;
  }

  for (i = offset; i < n; i++) {
    res[k] += x[i];
  }

  return res;
}
```

For example, you have:

```
> sumByPart(rep(1, 500), 1330)
[1] 500

> sumByPart(rep(1, 1300), 1330)
[1] 1300

> sumByPart(rep(1, 5612), 1330)
[1] 1330 1330 1330 1330  292
```

And for your problem, you just need to do `sumByPart(df[[2]], 1330)`.